# Join 2 trees using Python (dendroPy or other libraries)

Tags: python, bioinformatics, phylogeny

I am working on phylogenies by using Python libraries (Bio.Phylo and DendroPy).

I have to import 2 trees in Newick format (this is obviously not the difficult part) and join them together, more precisely I have to add one tree at one tip/leaf of another.

I have tried with `add_child` and `new_child` methods from *DendroPy*, but without success.

How would I solve this issue?

Comment: Hi Erica! Since this is a bioinformatics programming question, you may find the friendly folks over at [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/) helpful as well. Many of the Python programmers here on StackOverflow will never have worked with phylogenies, Newick files, etc, but that will be bread and butter for many on Biostars.

Answer (score 0):

Without resorting to anything fancier than an editor
you could find your "tip" in tree1 and insert the string that is tree2 at that point.  (being nested sets and all)